# Fetching data behind username/password authentication

Tags: c#, cookies, screen-scraping, wget

I'd like to download some data from a forum. The page containing the data is visible only to registered users. Here's an example webpage containing user data;

http://www.bikeforums.net/member.php/227664-StackOverflow

I'd like to get the data using wget or C#. I tried logging in via Firefox, then passing the cookies file (hopefully containing the login information) to wget. That was more of a makeshift hack and not a real solution, but it still failed. How do I do this properly?

I set up an account for testing if that's helpful.

User: StackOverflow

Pass: so123

Answer (score 0):

Using firebug you can easily get the POST data for the login page and use it to create a WebRequest and Login to the Forum.

The Server create the cookies for authentication and we can use this cookies in the next request on the forum page so the server can authenticate the request and return all the data.

Here I've tested a simple console application that achieves this mechanism.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;



namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest wpost = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.bikeforums.net/login.php?do=login");
            wpost.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            wpost.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "do=login&vb_login_md5password=d93bd4ce1af6a9deccaf0ea844d6c05d&vb_login_md5password_utf=d93bd4ce1af6a9deccaf0ea844d6c05d&s=&securitytoken=guest&url=%2Fmember.php%2F227664-StackOverflow&vb_login_username=StackOverflow&vb_login_password=";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            wpost.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            wpost.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            System.IO.Stream dataStream = wpost.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) wpost.GetResponse();

            // Request 
            wpost = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.bikeforums.net/member.php/227664-StackOverflow");

            //Assing the cookies created on the server to the new request
            wpost.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            wpost.Method = "GET";
             response = (HttpWebResponse)wpost.GetResponse();

             Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
             // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
             StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            //Display the result to console...
             Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
             response.Close();
             readStream.Close();

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```